# Is Access 2007 faster than Access 2013?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-office

We have an access database inside two servers, server A (Has access 2007) and server B (Which is 2x more powerful than the server A, this one has Access 2013).

The tables included in the query are:

```
AA (29,000 rows)
BB (6,000,000 rows)
CC (32 rows)
```

We're making a query that makes a `LEFT JOIN` between table AA and BB and an `INNER JOIN` between, in server A it takes 40 minutes and in Server B takes 10 hours.

Do MS Access 2007 uses different logic to perform some queries?

Comment: Please give as much of a [mcve] as you can. Is the DDL, DML & other code really the same?

Comment: Microsoft Access is not a server side database program, so what is "on the server" does not clearly have any meaning or consequence, it is what client version of Access is accessing the database file. [Ways to share an Access desktop database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-desktop-database-03822632-da43-4d8f-ba2a-68da245a0446)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Access 2013 is much optimized and highlights improvements that make Access faster and more reliable. Access 2013 makes it easier and faster to create a professional looking, functional database with huge data.

Also many things depend on your database architecture ...

Comment: This is a recommendation and should therefore be a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your notice, but i can't comment.... need some reputation for it :)

Comment: I am aware of your reputation and the limitations you experienced. Nevertheless, this does not provide an answer to the question and will therefore be deleted.